# Is $\frac{1}{x^2}$ Lebesgue integrable while $\frac{1}{x}$ is not?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

My textbook defined integrability as $f$ is said to be Lebesgue integrable if $\int{}f$ is finite.

I heard that $\frac1x$ is not Lebesgue integrable, but $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I do not agree with the fact above. $\int\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not finite, I think. I know $\sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty$, but $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. However, $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2}dx = \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_0^1 = -1 + \infty = +\infty$, which is not finite.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223439/showing-1-x2-is-lebesgue-integrable-on-mathbbr-ge-1

Comment: If a function is (properly) Riemann integrable it is also Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Think about the sums $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n^2}$. The first one is infinite while the second one is finite.

Comment: @Marc I know $\sum{\frac1n}=\infty$, but $\sum{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. However, $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2}dx = \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_0^1 = -1 + \infty = +\infty$, which is not finite.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä You mean $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is integrable in the sense of Riemann?

Comment: You are right, it is not integrable on $[0,1]$, it is however integrable on $[1,\infty]$.

Comment: Consider the family of functions $f_\alpha(x) = 1/x^\alpha$. It believe it can be shown that they are integrable on $[0,1]$ if $\alpha < 1$ and integrable on $[1,\infty)$ if $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: @SteamyRoot Ah.. Thank you. This is a great core point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "naked" expression $\int f$ makes no sense. We can, however, talk about the *definite integrals*
$$\int_1^\infty{1\over x}\>dx,\qquad \int_1^\infty{1\over x^2}\>dx\ .\tag{1}$$

In the Riemann integral environment these integrals are not bona-fide integrals, but should be considered as *improper integrals*. This means that one resorts to
$$\int_1^\infty{1\over x}\>dx:=\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_1^b{1\over x}\>dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\log b=\infty\ ,$$
hence the integral is *divergent*, and similarly
$$\int_1^\infty{1\over x^2}\>dx:=\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_1^b{1\over x^2}\>dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}-{1\over x}\biggr|_1^b=1\ .$$
In the Lebesgue framework both integrals $(1)$ are thought of right from the start as ranging over the interval $[1,\infty[\>$. The first then has the value $\infty$, hence $x\mapsto{1\over x}$ is not integrable over this interval, and the second of course  proudly (i.e., not obtained by some  exception-handling) has the value $1$.

Comment: The "naked" expression $\int f$ (more often written $\int f(t) dt$ or some other variable) typically means "a primitive of $f$", no?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: You have a point here. More precisely: The expression $\int f(t)\>dt$ denotes the set of all primitives of $f$ on the understood interval.

Comment: This answer gave me detailed information. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing is the domain. You're integrable ON something.

For instance, $$\int_0^1 \frac 1{x^2}dx=[-1/x]_0^1=+\infty$$ so $x\mapsto \frac 1{x^2}$ isn't integrable on $[0,1]$.

However, $$\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^2}dx=[-1/x]_1^\infty=1<+\infty$$ so $x\mapsto \frac 1{x^2}$ is integrable on $[1,\infty[$.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my question.